# Some theme elements broken after upgrade to 16.10?

Tags: unity, upgrade, themes

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10 today, I noticed that some UI elements changed and I wonder, wether this is wanted or not.

[image: problems]

This image shows the problems:

1. The borders of text field in Firefox look black
2. There is a gap between date and time in the top right corner
3. The scrollbar looks weird

I am using a Nvidia GTX 960, so might be driver related.